# angularjs not detecting the redirect url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, angular-routing

I am working on foursquare authentication in angularjs. When the foursquare redirects the user to the configured REDIRECT_URI, the angularjs automatically strips the query params and lands me in a different URI.

The following is the link where the browser is redirected to at first.

```
http://localhost:9000/foursquare?code=XXXXXXXXXX#_=_
```

Then within a second, it redirects me to

```
http://localhost:9000/foursquare
```

Thus I end up losing the query parameters.

After referring the [angularjs URL routing documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) I have the following snippet in my routes.js

```
.state('foursquare',{
        url:'/foursquare?code',
        templateUrl:'views/foursquare.html',
        controller:'mediaCtrl'
      })
```

Even then the same problem persists.
I am struck with this. Any help would be appreciated.

I am attaching the complete routes.js file

```
 'use strict';

    angular.module('nextpageApp')
      .config(function ($stateProvider) {


    $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .state('foursquare',{
        url:'/foursquare?code',
        templateUrl:'views/foursquare.html',
        controller:'mediaCtrl'
      })
      .state('why-citibytes', {
        url: '/why-citibytes',
        templateUrl: 'views/why-citibytes.html'
      })
      .state('small-businesses', {
        url: '/small-businesses',
        templateUrl: 'views/small-businesses.html'
      })
      .state('resellers', {
        url: '/resellers',
        templateUrl: 'views/resellers.html'
      })
     .state('groups', {
        url: '/groups-franchises',
        templateUrl: 'views/groups-franchises.html'
      })
     .state('publishers', {
        url: '/publishers',
        templateUrl: 'views/publishers.html'
      })
      .state('pricing', {
        url: '/pricing',
        templateUrl: 'views/pricing.html'
      })
      .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html'
      })
      .state('faq', {
        url: '/faq',
        templateUrl: 'views/faq.html'
      })
      .state('contact', {
        url: '/contact',
        templateUrl: 'views/contact-us.html'
      })
      .state('places', {
        url: '/places/:businessId',
        templateUrl: 'views/profile.html',
        controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
      })
      .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard/:businessId',
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
        controller:'DashboardCtrl',
        data: { title: 'My Page' },
        authenticate: true
      })
      .state('my-publishers', {
        url: '/publishers/:businessId',
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
        controller:'DashboardCtrl',
        data: { title: 'Pusblishers' },
        authenticate: true
      })
      .state('scan', {
        url: '/scan',
        templateUrl: 'views/scan.html',
        controller:'ScanCtrl'
      })
     // .state('test',{
//  url:'/test',
//  templateUrl:'views/test.html',
//  controller:'mainCtrl'
 //     })
      .state('build', {
        url: '/build',
        templateUrl: 'views/build.html',
        controller:'DashboardCtrl',
        authenticate: true
      });
  });
```

Following is the redirect URI that I have configured in the foursquare app

```
http://localhost:9000/foursquare
```

Comment: Things seem fine so far, there must be something in the rest of your code that isn't right. Do you mind sharing the rest of your routes at least?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jeff. I have added the source code of my routes.js file.